# MS Excel deleting the 0’s in the excel download of the report

Tags: excel, obiee

MS Excel deleting the 0’s in the excel download of the report  in OBIEE.

I have one primary id which has data like 001,002,003
The column is varchar and is treated as string in the report but when I export that to excel I'm getting 1,2,3.But I need the data should be like 001,002,003 only even after export.

I think excel is thinking this is number so it is cutting off zeros.

The user want to see data in excel exactly how it is displaying in report.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: What is the exact process? Doesn't OBIEE generate a delimited text file which can then be imported into Excel?  If that is the case, you need to **import** the file into Excel and define that column as text, at that point.

Comment: The user is not preferring a work around. He wants to export the report as excel file in OBIEE where the the data should be like 001,002,003 only even after export.

Comment: If OBIEE is exporting as a delimited text file, user will have to learn how to properly import a delimited file.  But you have chosen to keep the type of file and the export/import process that you are using secret, so I can't help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You're sadly not specifying on which exact version this happens. The problem is definitely Excel and since this is a known issue, Oracle introduced a setting in OBIEE some years back. It lets you define whether to transfer raw data to Excel (as above where Excel then messes it up) or formatted, in which case your string stays a string.

In the instanceconfig.xml you can set the following:

UseFormattedValue

When you set that to UseFormattedValue, Execl is forced to accept the actual formatting. Not what Excel *thinks* the data is.

The other setting is UseRawValue.

Comment: I'm not really that familiar with OBIEE. And the support documents are not freely available online. But from what little I see, are you sure that won't still drop leading zero's? The documentation I found indicated that the file is still going to be a delimited text file, but that this setting would allow output of rounded values rather than values with full precision.